# Оформление закладок с помощью css: наложение одной закладки на другую

Tags: html, css, css3, position, z-index

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать корректное отображение наложения закладок одну на другую слева направо.

Вроде как надо z-index аккуратно проманирулировать, но что-то не выходит.
Когда выставляю более высокий z-index для выделенного (dmm-selected) элемента, он вообще пропадает

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4jd65us/)

```css
.menu {
  user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0090d0;
  text-align: left;
}


/* выпадающее меню */

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* меню - элементы первого уровня */

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px -5px 0px -5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #fefefe;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #404040;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -11px;
  height: 0;
  width: calc(100% + 0px);
  border-bottom: 32px solid rgba(0, 144, 208, 0.25);
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li.ddm-selected {
  border-bottom: 32px solid #f8f8f8;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li.ddm-selected:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -12px;
  bottom: -2px;
  height: 0;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  border-bottom: 34px solid #0090d0;
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li:not(.ddm-selected):hover {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #fafdfe;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='dropdown-menu'>
    <ul>
      <li>Закладка #1</li>
      <li class='ddm-selected'>Закладка #2</li>
      <li>Закладка #3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Только с помощью css?

Comment: Оберни их какой-нить оберткой и все будет в шоколаде

Comment: Александр - да, очень хотелось бы только через css

Air, это как? Во что ты предлагаешь завернуть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так?

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $('ul > li').removeClass('ddm-selected');
  $(this).addClass('ddm-selected')
});
```

```css
.menu {
  user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0090d0;
  text-align: left;
}


/* выпадающее меню */

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* меню - элементы первого уровня */

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px -5px 0px -5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #fefefe;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #404040;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li:before,
.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -11px;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 32px solid rgba(0, 144, 208, 0.25);
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li:before {
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li.ddm-selected {
  border-bottom: 32px solid #f8f8f8;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li.ddm-selected:before,
.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li.ddm-selected:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -12px;
  bottom: -2px;
  height: 0;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  border-bottom: 34px solid #0090d0;
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li.ddm-selected:before {
  top: 0;
  left: -11px;
  border-bottom: 34px solid #ffffff;
  width: calc(100%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul:first-child>li:not(.ddm-selected):hover {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #fafdfe;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='dropdown-menu'>
    <ul>
      <li>Закладка #1</li>
      <li class='ddm-selected'>Закладка #2</li>
      <li>Закладка #3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Принцип следующий, вы накладываете сверху такой же элемент белого цвета со смещением и тем самым создаете контур. А дальше уже играйтесь через `z-index` сколько вам захочется.

Comment: Алексей, то что надо!
Сейчас попробую понять в чем ошибка у меня была

Comment: Алексей, а можно еще пояснить - т.е. я использую 2 элемента :before, :after и в итоге у меня получается слоёный пирог из 3 элементов :before, :after, content

вот никак понять не могу почему надо использовать второй псевдоэлемент

Comment: @Zhihar у вас 2 псевдоэлемента одинаковой формы, но разных цветов  и разного положения. Вы накладываете один с синим фоном, на него второй с белым и даете им отрицательный `z-index`, чтоб они были за текстом. Попробуйте, например, убрать `:before` для пункта списка и увидите разницу. Или задать ему другой отступ сверху.